# Why not $(a,b)$ is not possible to define $\rho(f, g)$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

According to C.Adam's Topology: [image: Photo]

I don't know about compactness, but before introducing compactness in this book, in one of exercises it is asked: "Explain why we cannot generally define $\rho(f, g)$ for functions $f$ and $g$ that are continuous on the open interval $(a, b)$".

I have no clue to understand why it must be closed interval, to define $\rho(f, g)$? I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Consider the functions $f(x)=0$ and $g(x)=\frac1x$ on the interval $(0,1)$.

Comment: Do you mean: it is BECAUSE on any closed interval of $[a,b]$ we never can define some function such that $f(a_0)=\infty$? Am I right?

Comment: @Ali.E.: Almost: on a closed interval you can be sure that every continuous function is bounded.